# for loop range - result in columns/horizontally

Tags: python, for-loop, range

How can i get result in columns instead?, i have tried with for [a-c], (a-c), but it will give error message.

```
for a in range(1,6):
    print(f'{a}')

for b in range(1,6):
    print(f'{b}')

for c in range(1,6):
    print(f'{c}')
```

**Desired result:**

```
1    1    1
2    2    2
3    3    3
4    4    4  
5    5    5
```

**Current result:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Your question is basically: "how do I print without a new line?".  And the answer is `print(a, end='')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `end` from `\n` to space  :

```
for a in range(1,6):
    print(f'{a}', end=' ')
print()

for b in range(1,6):
    print(f'{b}', end=' ')
print()

for c in range(1,6):
    print(f'{c}', end=' ')
print()
```

** UPDATE **:
after updating your question, here is my solution:

```
a = range(1, 6)
b = range(1, 6)
c = range(1, 6)

for index in range(len(a)):
    print(f'{a[index]}    {b[index]}    {c[index]}')
```

output:

```
1    1    1
2    2    2
3    3    3
4    4    4
5    5    5
```

Comment: Sorry, i meant, that i would like to have the result in columns (in above case, for example 3 columns).

Comment: @PeterN not sure I understand. Can you add your expected output?

Comment: i have updated my question (it should be in columns), thanks